# Inspecting Storage Slots in Everscale Smart Contracts

Tags: solidity, everscale

I'm trying to figure out how to inspect the contents of storage slots in Everscale smart contracts. In Solidity, it's straightforward to map variables to storage slots and view them, but I can't find a similar process for Everscale. How can I access and read the storage slots of an Everscale smart contract?

I've looked through Everscale developer tools but haven't found a way to read storage slots directly as I would in Ethereum using web3.eth.getStorageAt(). I attempted to use the Everscale SDK and TONOS CLI, anticipating functionality similar to Ethereum's, but the process for accessing storage slots isn't clear to me. Any pointers or tools for inspecting smart contract storage in Everscale would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example, there is a contract [0:3ca696295870064d33553aae84f41c4aaffff55e1988cb87a5dd67640fbf8787](https://everscan.io/accounts/0:3ca696295870064d33553aae84f41c4aaffff55e1988cb87a5dd67640fbf8787). You take the Data and ABI or TLB-scheme if the data structure is unknown, then you match it.
[image]

In this case, the data structure is as follows: `uint256,bool,uint8,map(uint256,uint8),address,cell,uint32,uint16,uint16,address,uint32`, and you can read the data through utilities or here [ever.bytie.moe/deserializer](https://ever.bytie.moe/deserializer).

[image]

**The screenshot shows that the **"Allow partial"** option is selected, which means that the description of the data structure is incomplete and we deserialize it as is.*